# Console application with dependency injection exiting with code 0, without error or exception. What could be a problem?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, console-application

I have to develop a .NET console application(name: Port), which references class library project(name: Data) that has data models and so on...

In the Data project, there is static class with static method for extension of `IServiceCollection`, it looks something like this

```
public static class ServiceCollectionsFish
{
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterFishServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<FishContext>(o =>
        {
            o.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Legacy"));
            o.EnableDetailedErrors();
            o.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        });

        services.AddTransient<IBrandRepository, BrandRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IBrandGroupRepository, BrandGroupRepository>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

I would like to mention that this Data project is also referenced in WEB API project and works like a charm.

Now, my console application, has Program.cs class, and appsettings.json file. In Program.cs I have a static method for building a configuration

```
    static void BuildConfig(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }
```

And the main method, which uses instance of Start class and invokes its Test() method:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        BuildConfig(builder);

        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.RegisterFishServices(builder.Build());
                services.AddTransient<IStart, Start>();
            }).Build();

        var start = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Start>(host.Services);
        start.Test();
    }
```

Now, the Start class, has simple logic, using IBrandRepository(injected), in the Test() method should return data from database, and just print it(for testing purposes). It actually never gets to the `Console.WriteLine(brand)` line, application just stops with code 0, without throwing an exception. It is also interesting, if I do this in constructor of Start class, it works !

```
public class Start : IStart
{
    private readonly IBrandRepository _brandRepository;

    public Start(IBrandRepository brandRepository)
    {
        _brandRepository = brandRepository;
        //works
        Brand_ brand = _brandRepository.GetById(new Guid("8D09F3E2-322B-4AFF-A4F2-57BDE98A78B5")).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
        //works
    }


    public async Task Test()
    {
        try
        {
            //exit the program
            Brand_? brand = await _brandRepository.GetById(new Guid("8D09F3E2-322B-4AFF-A4F2-57BDE98A78B5"));
            Console.WriteLine(brand);
            Console.WriteLine("OK");
            //exit the program
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` you async method or  you're just starting the Task in the console app, not waiting for it to finish. You should also update the `Main` method signature to be asynchronous.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    await start.Test();
}
```

Comment: Right. But then I recieve an error. CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? `async` Main has been possible since C# 7.1. You could always use a blocking call if you can't update the version: `start.Test().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Comment: I'm using C# 11 and .NET Core 7

Comment: Check your code and project settings again - a Main method declared like in this answer works just fine in .NET 7 and C# 11. https://dotnetfiddle.net/ukwA8Y

Comment: Actually this resolved my issue. All I needed is to await Test() method, and make Main method async Task !!! Thank you :)